# file upload with html upload too slow compared to winscp upload

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

I just did a comparison for a image file upload for a gif file size 8.5mb.
when I upload the same using winscp to my server, it takes 4 seconds.
similarly If I upload the same in Gmail it takes 6 seconds.

but when I use html file upload for sending file, it takes 33seconds - 2 seconds server processing. so net 31 seconds.

I tried with joomla file upload as well, here also I am getting around the same 33 seconds.

only gmail is almost similar to winscp.

is this a browser limitation and is there a way to address this?

Comment: You're doing this on the same device with the same internet connection?

Comment: yes on the same device with same internet connection. my connection is fiber with 100mbps upload speed.

Comment: OK, and are you FTP'ing to the same server as you're trying to upload the image? I think you do. I don't think there should be a large difference between FTP and HTTP, unless your hoster imposes that difference?

Comment: yes that's right. I tried again just now. it took around 4 seconds.

Comment: I tried with two different server, one is a dedicated one and another is a vps, in both cases I am getting this slow upload with file upload, but faster upload with winscp. and software installed is completely by myself. what is it possibly I can check as the server proivder I am sure there is no restriction from there.

Comment: No the 4 seconds I tried again was with winscp and not http.

Comment: could it be apache or php?

Comment: The difference is very big, and I don't think it is PHP, although I cannot completely exclude it. I have one last idea: It could be that outgoing HTTP traffic is going through a special firewall on your computer, to scan for privacy violations. Some virus-scanners use those, sometimes in the form of a plug-in of the browser. It could possible slow things down? I would not use GMail as a benchmark, Google can do all sorts of weird things, and have all sorts of exceptions, because it is Google, especially on the Chrome browser.

Comment: is there a way I can identify that, as I tried to disable antivirus to see if this possibly could be the reason. but I didn't get any better result

Comment: There are so-called "developer tools" in your browser. They allow you to diagnose all sort of things, including this one. It does take a while to learn to use these tools however.

Comment: in winscp there are different protocols for connection - in scp mode I get the speed this fast, but If I try sftp It takes around 12 seconds. plain ftp I haven't tried yet.

Comment: I don't use WinSCP, and have no clue what SCP mode is. Ah, wikipedia says: [Secure copy protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy_protocol).